trying to insert into returning
Good Afternoon,
I am trying to run the following code:
Sub doit()
Dim oCmd As Object

    oraCon.openConnection "EPAT", "minhaszt", "CaMgNa_2024"
    oraFunc.setConnection oraCon
    Set NAME_VAL = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
    With NAME_VAL
        .Name = "NAME_VAL"
        .Type = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar
        .Direction = ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput
        .Value = "FREDO"
        .Size = Len("FREDO")
    End With
    Set ID_VAL = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
    With ID_VAL
        .Name = "ID_VAL"
        .Type = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar
        .Direction = ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput
        .Size = 5
    End With
    Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    With oCmd
        .Parameters.Append NAME_VAL
        .Parameters.Append ID_VAL
        .ActiveConnection = oraFunc.getConnection
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(NAME1) VALUES(:NAME_VAL) RETURNING ID1 INTO :ID_VAL;"
        
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    Rem this returns empty
    Debug.Print ID_VAL.Value

    While oCmd.Parameters.Count > 0
        oCmd.Parameters.Delete (0)
    Wend
End Sub

I am only allowed to connect via odbc, using company provided DSN`s.
I am running the above test code. It successfully inserts, but does not return back the ID1 value.
I would appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you for your assistance.

You are using positional bind parameters ? in the query but in the parameters you are specifying named bind parameters.
Use the named bind parameters throughout:
INSERT INTO TABLE1(NAME1) VALUES (:NAME_VAL) RETURNING ID1 INTO :ID_VAL


Hello, I made the change as requested. Now I get the error message 'Run-Time error -2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified err

I have furhter modifications, and i am getting the error: "Not all variables are boind"
